# Searching for -[] results in weirdness

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, search

Try [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/-) and hover on the empty tag the sidebar shows. You can also make your own query; try `[tag] -[*]`.

[image]

The empty tag really shouldn't exist/be shown. If you search `[*]` it seems to recognize that's not a real search. It only lets you search the empty tag if you search `[tag] -[*]` or if you just construct a URL like I have above.

Hovering on the empty tag clears the page and presents this:
[image]

And if you hover over it the page turns completely blank.

Comment: Easter egg!! :)

Comment: Wow.  Repro'd on Chrome 17.0.963.33 beta-m on Windows XP.  I hope this is not thrashing the server or anything :P

Comment: In IE8 the screen instantly goes blank on hovering over the blank tag, with the only contents being: `<DIV style="MARGIN: 15px 0px; MIN-HEIGHT: 220px" class=hireme></DIV>`

Comment: Blank screen on Firefox too, very nice find!

Comment: Does this qualify for a hacker badge? :p hahahahahahah

Comment: @jcolebrand only if you get a tag badge in [tag:*]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is now a secondary pass on the tag array to check for and strip these invalid "-" only tag names and remove them.

For example, [`/questions/tagged/-`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/-) will now redirect to `/questions` as a result.

Comment: Man, somebody's on a roll today!